# On polynomials over finite fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, finite-fields

Pick prime $q\in\Bbb Z$ such that $q>B^{3t}>(mB)^{2t}$.

Suppose I have a multilinear polynomial $g(x)\in \Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ of degree $t$ with $m^t$ non-zero coefficients that bound by $|B|>2$, I pick a set $S\subseteq \Bbb Z^n$ such that $|S|<\infty$ and each element of $S$ is bounded by $B$.

Let $\forall s\in S,\mbox{ }g(s)\in[-(mB)^t,(mB)^t]\bigcap\Bbb Z$ and $q\nmid g(s)$.

Let $h(x)=g^2(x)$. So $\forall s\in S,\mbox{ }h(s)\in[0,(mB)^{2t}]\bigcap\Bbb Z$ and coefficients of $h(x)$ are bound by $m^{2t}|B|^2$.

Consider $h(x)$ as element in $\Bbb F_{q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Call this element $\hat{h}(x)$.

Hence $\hat{H}(x)=\hat{h}^{q-1}(x)$ always takes values in $\{0,1\}$ when evaluated on $S$ and has coefficients in $\{0,1\}$. Is this observation correct?

Now consider $\hat{H}(x)$ as sitting in $\Bbb Z[x]$ and call this polynomial $H(x)$.

Since $q>B^{3t}>(mB)^{2t}$, and we evaluate on $S$, $x_i^{q-1}$ can replaced by $x_i$ in $\hat{H}(x)$ where $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ now. Call this element as $\hat{H}_l(x)$ in $\Bbb F_{q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. $\hat{H}_l(x)$ and $\hat{H}(x)$ take same value (either $0$ or $1$) in $S$.

Call the $\hat{H}_l(x)$  when considered as an element in $\Bbb Z[x]$ as $H_l(x)$. Now we evaluate $H_l(x)$ in $\{0,1\}^n$.

Precisely, does $$H_l(x)=0\iff\hat{H}_l(x)=0\iff\hat{H}(x)=0
\iff H(x)=0$$$$\iff \hat{h}(x)=0\iff h(x)=0\iff g(x)=0$$ hold true when evaluated on $\{0,1\}^n$?

Is there a way to force the evaluations of some modification of $H_l(x)$ to $\{0,1\}$ when evaluated on $\{0,1\}^n$?
Are there any studies of transferring results in polynomials over finite fields to polynomials over integer coefficients?

Comment: The coefficients of $h$ aren't guaranteed to be bounded by $|B|^2$. e.g. $(wx+wy+wz+xy+xz+yz)^2 = 6 wxyz + \text{other stuff}$

Comment: Is the bound $2^{2t}|B|^2$?

Comment: Also, I don't see why you consider $\mathbf{F}_{q^{2q}}$: everything about this problem lies in the subfield $\mathbf{F}_q$. Or, did you mean the integers modulo $q^{2q}$ instead? (in which case we can't assume $H$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$)

Comment: Ok this is my problem. If I have a degree $t$ multilinear polynomial that takes $B$ bounded values and some zeros, what is the degree of the multilinear polynomial that will that $1$ as non zero values wherever the original polynomial takes non-zero values and coincides with the zeros.

Comment: I am trying to put $Z[x]$ in some large cardinality finite field. and get a polynomial in that field with some coefficients but taking $0$ and $1$ values. Since the caridnality is large, the $1$ does not occur because of $kq^c+1$ for some $c,k>0$ but occurs genuinely because it was $1$ in the bigger finite field and hence it will take $1$ when considered as polynomial in $Z[x]$.

Comment: do I make sense?

Comment: A possible bound on the coefficients is $|B|^2 \cdot (\text{number of terms of }h)$, so you could work out the number of possible terms a polynomial can have and plug that in (although you can do better than that).

Comment: A problem with what I think your plan is is, for example, that $q+1 = 1$ in any field of characteristic $q$, such as $\mathbf{F}_{q^{2q}}$.

Comment: You mean $(n+1)^t$? That sounds right.

Comment: what if we assume $\forall s\in S,\mbox{ }q\nmid g(s)$ holds true?

Comment: @Hurkyl do the changes now make some sense?